# password_verify returns false. cant find error

Tags: php, passwords, password-protection, password-encryption, password-hash

I have been trying to figure out this problem for about 2 months and can't seem to figure it out. I have a database that returns the hashed password. I can confirm this works due to printing out all the information. It can return the non-hashed and hashed password perfectly fine but when it checks the password it will always return false.

I am not sure what to do. It could be something really easy but I seem to not be able to find it.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $dbip = "localhost";
    $dbuser = "root";
    $dbpass = "";
    $dbname = "projectNitro";
    $conn = new mysqli($dbip, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

    if($conn->connect_error) {
        echo("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET["pass"]);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET["email"]);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='{$email}' LIMIT 1";
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $pass = $_GET["pass"];

    if($query == TRUE) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
        $db_password = $row['password'];
        $db_usertype = $row['accountType'];
        $username = $row['username'];
        echo $password;
        echo "<br>";
        echo $db_password;
        echo "<br>";
        $verify = password_verify($pass, $db_password);

        if($verify) {
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            $_SESSION['at'] = $db_usertype;
            header("Location: http://website.com");
        } else {    
            echo("DB Email: "
            .$row["email"]
            ."<br>Username: "
            .$row["username"]
            ."<br>DB Password: "
            .$row["password"]
            ."<br>AccountType: "
            .$row["accountType"]
            ."<br>Inserted Email: "
            .$_GET["email"]
            ."<br>Inserted Password: "
            .$_GET["pass"]."<br>");

            if(password_verify($_GET["pass"], $row["password"])) {
                echo("epic<br>");
            } else {
                echo("not epic<br>");
            }
        }
    } else {
        header("Location: http://website.com");
    }
    $conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: INDENT. Do you think it's good design to have your users' passwords as part of a URL?

Comment: @miken32 I am currently using get to make sure that the system will work, then will switch to post.

Comment: Start the way you mean to finish. You need to format your code properly if you want anyone to look at it. I'd also suggest adding the code that stores the hash, and ensuring you wipe out your database for testing purposes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do baby steps. keep stepping up as long as it works.

Here is a simpler version of your code that should work with the password sample from the official doc: http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Also use `die();` to debug your code in every `{}` block.
In your current code you redirect to a website in both cases it's really hard to track what is wrong if you are redirected!

You have useless and unclear variables, for instance `$dbpass`, `$db_password` is very ambiguous, even if you and I understand it makes it not maintainable. As well as your coding style, you need to indent!

The next step you need to check if this code works, is replace the hard coded password with a hard coded password you have with hard coded hash as well.

```
<?php

session_start();
$dbip = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "";
$dbname = "projectNitro";
$conn = new mysqli($dbip, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error){
  echo("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error) . '<br><br>';
}

$password = 'rasmuslerdorf';//mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET["pass"]);
// $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET["email"]);
// $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='{$email}' LIMIT 1";
// $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
// $pass = $_GET["pass"];

// if ($query == TRUE) {
  // $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
  $db_password = '$2y$07$BCryptRequires22Chrcte/VlQH0piJtjXl.0t1XkA8pw9dMXTpOq';
  // $username = $row['username'];

  echo $password;
  echo "<br>";
  echo $db_password;
  echo "<br>";

  if (password_verify($password, $db_password)) {
    die('ok');
  } else {
    die('not ok');
  }
// } else {
//   header("Location: http://website.com");
// }

$conn->close();
?>
```

---

Here I modified slightly and added a few comments along the code to help you understand the approach.

```
<?php

session_start();

// This array is used only like a simple namespace.
$dbCredentials = [
  'host' => "localhost",
  'user' => "root",
  'password' => "",
  'dbname' => "projectNitro"
];
$dbConn = new mysqli($dbCredentials['host'], $dbCredentials['user'], $dbCredentials['password'], $dbCredentials['dbname']);

if ($dbConn->connect_error) {
  // Should not continue script if can't connect to DB.
  die("Connection failed: " . $dbConn->dbConnect_error);
}

// You should check the existence of $_GET["pass"] before using it, with empty() or isset().
$passwordToCheck = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbConn, $_GET["pass"]);// Renamed var more meaningful.
$userEmail = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbConn, $_GET["email"]);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='{$userEmail}' LIMIT 1";// Don't select * if you don't need everything.
$query = mysqli_query($dbConn, $sql);
$pass = $_GET["pass"];// you already have $passwordToCheck.

if ($query) {// Don't need == TRUE
  // $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
  $db_password = '$2y$07$BCryptRequires22Chrcte/VlQH0piJtjXl.0t1XkA8pw9dMXTpOq';
  $username = $row['username'];

  echo "$passwordToCheck<br>$db_password<br>";// This is way less verbose than repeating echo and uses less echo functions.

  if (password_verify($passwordToCheck, $db_password)) {// Don't need to keep this condition in a variable. 
    die('ok');// this is just an example to test.
  } else {
    die('not ok');// this is just an example to test.
  }
} else {
  header("Location: http://website.com");// While debugging don't redirect, put die('message');
}

$dbConn->close();
?>
```

Comment: The modified code works find with a hardcoded password but once I connect it to the database and try it, the password fails to verify.

Comment: @MineCakePvP - That sounds like the stored hash is the problem. Did you check that you used `varchar(255)` to store the hash? Also check that the hash is generated correctly with `password_hash()`, often some invisible characters like newlines are the problem.

Comment: @martinstoeckli is right, and you can also try this working hash in your database! Replace your hash and paste this one instead, if it does not work it means you don't read this field properly be sure to not mysqli_real_escape_string it when you compare it.

Comment: @antoni I made sure that the password is hashed with password_hash() and made sure that the table is using varchar with the length of 255 and it still doesn't works.

Comment: You should read your database hash, then `die(print_r(['your_hardcoded_password', $db_password, password_verify('your_hardcoded_password', $db_password)], true));` can you tell me the result?